# How to setup Apache subdomain to point to a virtual machine web server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization, subdomain

I am trying to solve a problem, with a Linux server work as host, while qemu guest will have another server intended for subdomain.

The guest server is bridged correctly with the host server. The host server can access the webpage in the guest, and so does guest to host, with correct IP.

I am trying to create subdomain from the host Apache so that the subdomain can map the guest server. I have tried with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961311/pointing-a-subdomain-to-another-ip-via-apache).

As a result, it works fine only when I access the subdomain, example `http://mysub.mydomain`. However, when I try to access `http://mydomain`, then it fails with following error.

```
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Is there any solution?

(Added 2013-04-12) The following is the Apache configuration added.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysub.mydomain
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyErrorOverride On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.100.2/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.100.2/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your apache config?

Comment: @DavidHoude, updated as request.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution with another way. That is without using the Apache for the subdomain.

Since domain name is related to the DNS, and my website is currently for local network only, thus the best way is to use the IP, and if needed, edit the /etc/hosts for that two different servers will work as same domain.